# How to regexp_extract if a matching pattern resides anywhere in the string - pyspark

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pattern-matching

I was trying to get some insights on regexp_extract in pyspark and I tried to do a check with this option to get better understanding.

Below is my dataframe

```
data = [('2345', 'Checked|by John|for kamal'),
('2398', 'Checked|by John|for kamal '),
('2328', 'Verified|by Srinivas|for kamal than some random text'),        
('3983', 'Verified|for Stacy|by John')]

df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['ID', 'Notes'])

df.show()

+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  ID|               Notes                                 |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
|2345|Checked|by John|for kamal                            |
|2398|Checked|by John|for kamal                            |
|2328|Verified|by Srinivas|for kamal than some random text |
|3983|Verified|for Stacy|by John                           |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

So here I was trying to identify whether **an ID is checked or verified by John**

With the help of SO members I was able to crack the use of **regexp_extract**  and came to below solution

```
result = df.withColumn('Employee', regexp_extract(col('Notes'), '(Checked|Verified)(\\|by John)', 1))

result.show()

+----+------------------------------------------------+------------+
|  ID|               Notes                                |Employee|
+----+------------------------------------------------+------------+
|2345|Checked|by John|for kamal                           | Checked|
|2398|Checked|by John|for kamal                           | Checked|
|2328|Verified|by Srinivas|for kamal than some random text|        |
|3983|Verified|for Stacy|by John                          |        |
+----+--------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

For few ID's this gives me perfect result ,But for last ID it didn't print Verified. Could someone please let me know whether any other action needs to be performed in the mentioned regular expression?

What I feel is `(Checked|Verified)(\\|by John)` is matching only adjacent values. I tried * and $, still it didn't print Verified for ID 3983.

Answer (score 1):

I would have phrased the regex as:

```regex
(Checked|Verified)\b.*\bby John
```

### Demo

This pattern finds `Checked/Verified` followed by `by John` with the two separated by any amount of text.  Note that I just use word boundaries here instead of pipes.

Updated code:

```
result = df.withColumn('Employee', regexp_extract(col('Notes'), '\b(Checked|Verified)\b.*\bby John', 1))
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.But did that gave u the results. When I replaced my regular expression with urs,I did nt get any results.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to check if the column Notes contains a string `by John`:

```
   df.withColumn('Employee',F.when(col('Notes').like('%Checked|by John%'), 'Checked').when(col('Notes').like('%by John'), 'Verified').otherwise(" ")).show(truncate=False)

+----+----------------------------------------------------+--------+
|ID  |Notes                                               |Employee|
+----+----------------------------------------------------+--------+
|2345|Checked|by John|for kamal                           |Checked |
|2398|Checked|by John|for kamal                           |Checked |
|2328|Verified|by Srinivas|for kamal than some random text|        |
|3983|Verified|for Stacy|by John                          |Verified|
+----+----------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks! I am expecting the result as Verified for last ID

Comment: Me bad. It required multiple when outputs. See my edits

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.withColumn('Employee', F.regexp_extract('Notes', '(Checked|Verified)\\|.*by John', 1))

result.show()
+----+--------------------+--------+
|  ID|               Notes|Employee|
+----+--------------------+--------+
|2345|Checked|by John|f...| Checked|
|2398|Checked|by John|f...| Checked|
|2328|Verified|by Srini...|        |
|3983|Verified|for Stac...|Verified|
+----+--------------------+--------+
```